# Error Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Faced this error (below attached screenshot). I do not understand how to solve it correctly, the sequence of widgets is broken. Perhaps you have a solution to this problem, I will be grateful if you can help.

**file1**

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        child: Column(children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 22),
          TabBarLibrary(tabController: _tabController, size: size),
        ]),
      );
```

**file2**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TabBarView(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: widget.size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
              color: constants.Colors.greyDark.withOpacity(0.7),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 21, left: 12, bottom: 15, right: 24),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Text',
                    style: constants.Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  SizedBox(height: 188, child: CloseConnectionList()),
                  const SizedBox(height: 17),
                  const Text(
                    'Text',
                    style: constants.Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

**file3**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: Scrollbar(
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          thickness: 2,
          scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.left,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: close.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 9),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 47,
                child: Card(
                  color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 4,
                  ),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: constants.Colors.white,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 11,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            close[index],
                            style: constants.Styles.smallerLtStdTextStyleWhite,
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.barPoynts)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

**error**

> The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept
> ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly
> inside Flex widgets. The offending Expanded is currently placed inside
> a SizedBox widget.
>
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
> incompatible parent data was:   FocusTrapArea ← TextField ←
> UnmanagedRestorationScope ← TextFormField ← Expanded ← SizedBox ←
> SearchWidget ← Column ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← ⋯

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Expanded` in **file2**. It should only be direct child of `Row`, `Column` or `Flex`. Check the doc for more info.

Comment: And I have Expanded located inside Column in file1

Comment: From what you've posted I don't see Expanded in file1 code, but there is no problem if it is a direct child of Column.